# The pronunciation of Greek "γ"

Tags: greek, pronunciation

How is the **γ** in verbs like ***γ*ιγνώσκω** and ***γ*ίνομαι** pronounced in ancient Greek? Is it pronounced like **g** in ***g*et** or like **g** in ***g*em**?

Comment: The softening of g, c, etc. before e and i is not universal. Pronounce the γ hard as in get.

Comment: Depends if you are asking about modern or classical Greek.

Comment: @SimpliciterChristianus Modern Greek is off-topic, so I took the liberty to restrict the question to older Greek.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The letter gamma was pronounced like the *g* in *get* in Ancient Greek, a  voiced velar stop. But before another gamma, before kappa, chi, or xi, the gamma was pronounced like *ng*, as in *boring*. It's also pronounced like *ng* before at least some cases of nu or mu (possibly all).

More information, including the pronunciation in New Greek, can be found on Wikipaedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma

Comment: Gamma is thought to have been nasal (*ng*) also before nu and mu, either always or at least in some words.

Comment: @TKR: Added! <filler tex>

Comment: I like how "stop" ends with a stop consonant, and "voiced" ends with a voiced consonant. If only "velar" ended with a velar.

Comment: @ktm5124: That would be quite the coincidence!

Comment: @ktm5124 Actually, voiced ends with a voiced consonant in writing, but usually not in pronunciation, due to the unvoiced /s/ preceding it.

Comment: @CannedMan: Right, that is true.

Answer (score 1):

In modern Greek it is pronounced exactly like **y** in **yet**.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you be a little more specific? Most importantly, I would like to know what kind of Greek this answer applies to (modern?) and what it is based on (personal experience?).

Comment: I don't think anyone can know how the ancients pronounced it...But when a greek today pronounces these words (in modern or ancient greek) they pronounce "γ" as "y" in "year" and not any "g"

Comment: I edited your answer to give the context. Feel free to re-edit. // In fact, we do have knowledge of how things were pronounced two millennia ago. In fact, "How can we know how ancient Greek was pronounced?" would make a nice question if we don't have it already.

Comment: we only have assumptions... this applies to ancient greek music to.If you don't hear a song (since they were not written down) or hear a person speak, you can't know

Comment: This is true before front vowels only. Modern Greek γ followed by back vowels is IPA [γ], a voiced guttural fricative.

Comment: @ZaMoC Your comments reflect a lack of familiarity with comparative linguistics. We actually know quite a lot about how it was pronounced, not only from their own writings about it, but also from inscriptions in the various dialects of Greek, such inscriptions translated to other languages (maybe not as common as for Latin), and how non-Greeks discussed Greek. And this is only the tip of the iceberg; when you add comparative linguistics, you can include studies of how different sounds developed to modern languages, informing with reasonable certainty how they must have been pronounced earlier.

Comment: @CannedMan do you also have an opinion about the main question? The accepted answer is wrong. When we (modern greeks)  read modern or ancient greek, we do not pronounce γ as english people say gamma. So, "get" is wrong.  γ is "γαμμα" and not "γκαμα" as you pronounce it. Just use google translate and hear it. here is the link: https://translate.google.gr/?sl=el&tl=en&text=%CE%B3%CE%B9%CE%B3%CE%BD%CF%89%CF%83%CE%BA%CF%89%0A%0A&op=translate

Comment: I do, but it would take more research for me to provide a quality answer. As far as I know, Modern Greek pronounces γ as /ɣ/, which as it happens to be is the same as in Dutch, e.g. the initial G of van Gogh. Ancient Greek as altogether a different beast, but I think I have enough knowledge to write up an answer over the weekend or late next week.